# Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli,

Tags: javascript, sql

Estou tentando fazer um cadastro mas está dando um erro mostrado a seguir.

```
Notice: Undefined variable: conexao in C:\xampp\htdocs\telecom\cadastrar.php on line 4

Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\telecom\cadastrar.php on line 4

Notice: Undefined variable: conexao in C:\xampp\htdocs\telecom\cadastrar.php on line 5

Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\telecom\cadastrar.php on line 5

Notice: Undefined variable: conexao in C:\xampp\htdocs\telecom\cadastrar.php on line 6

Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\telecom\cadastrar.php on line 6

Notice: Undefined variable: conexao in C:\xampp\htdocs\telecom\cadastrar.php on line 9

Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\telecom\cadastrar.php on line 9

Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\telecom\cadastrar.php on line 10

Notice: Undefined variable: conexao in C:\xampp\htdocs\telecom\cadastrar.php on line 19

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\telecom\cadastrar.php:19 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\telecom\cadastrar.php on line 19
```

E esse é o codigo referente ao erro.

```
<?php
session_start();
include("conexao.php");
$nome = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, ($_POST['nome']));
$usuario = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, ($_POST['usuario']));
$senha = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, (md5($_POST['senha'])));

$sql = "select count(*) as total from usuario where usuario = '$usuario'";
$result = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
if($row['total'] == 1) {
    $_SESSION['usuario_existe'] = true;
    header('Location: cadastro.php');
    exit;
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO usuario (nome, usuario, senha, data_cadastro) VALUES ('$nome', '$usuario', '$senha', NOW())";

if($conexao->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    $_SESSION['status_cadastro'] = true;
}

$conexao->close();

header('Location: cadastro.php');
exit;
?>
```

Tentei achar uma solução mas não consegui.

Answer (score -1):

Tem que definir a natureza da variável  `$conexao` antes de usá-la.Veja no link abaixo a forma como proceder, talvez isso te ajude.
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp